# TYPO3: How to fix missing or not working language path segment

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x

My Typo3 website contains 3 languages: German (default), English and French. On the website there is a logo image which refers to the start page of the respective language when clicking on it.

In the German and English version this works as expected, in the French version it doesn't - it always refers to the German start page. I noticed that the country code is missing (/fr/) for all links in the French version, and that the abbreviation /en/ is displayed after the domain in the English version, as expected. How is that possible?

Here are my scripts for the language configuration:

config.ts

```
config {
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE.utf8
    sys_language_uid = 0
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    linkVars = L(0-2)
    uniqueLinkVars = 1
}

[...]

## Sprachen definieren

# Deutsch
temp.language = TEXT
temp.language.value = DE

# Englisch
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]

    config {
        language = en
        locale_all = en_GB.utf8
        sys_language_uid = 1
        htmlTag_langKey = en
        sys_language_overlay = 1
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback;0
    }

    temp.language.value = EN

[global]

# Franzoesisch
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]

    config {
        language = fr
        locale_all = fr_FR.utf8
        sys_language_uid = 2
        htmlTag_langKey = fr
        sys_language_overlay = 1
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback;0
    }

    temp.language.value = FR

[global]

lib.language < temp.language
```

The typoscript for the logo:

```
lib.logo = TEXT
lib.logo {
    value = <img src="path/to/logo.svg" class="logo-norm" border="0">
    typolink {
        parameter = 1
        additionalParams = COA
        additionalParams {
            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                data = GP:L
                intval = 1
                wrap = &L=|
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This looks like a problem/misconfiguration with realurl. Can you provide your realurl configuration for the language part?

Comment: If you have set config.linkVars = L(1).

you should use config.linkVars = L(int) or config.linkVars = L(0-2)

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/master/en-us/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html